# End of an async action inside _.each

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I have an asynchronous action happening inside the iterator function in _.each. Is there a way to call another function after the callback of the asynchronous action ends.

```
_.each(A, function (a){ 
    B(a, function (c, d) { 
        // statements
    }
}
```

I want to do something after for all items in A the callback function inside B has been finished. I'm using this in a node js server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you well, you want to execute an asynchronous function for each item in an array, and then call another function when all async calls have finished. To achieve this, you should use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module:

```
async.each(arr, function(item, callback){
  // some asynchronous function executed for every item in Arr
  // call callback function when done 
  callback();
, function(){
  // executed after all the iterator functions have finished
}
```

Please refer to [async documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) for more details and examples.

Comment: Don't we have access to any `variable` which is earlier set in any of the `callbacks` in the final `function()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a package like [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async). If you just want a one-off though, the short way is to use a simple counter:

```
var i = 0;
var done = function() {
    // Do Stuff
};

_.each(A, function(a) {
    B(a, function(c, d) {
        if ((i += 1) == A.length) done();
    });
});
```